# Do different action on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I develop an android app, and I have two menus in action bar, I make an action for each of them, but I only able to access one of them, this is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Studentsite News", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ssnews.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected1(MenuItem item)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "About", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, about.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

Do you any idea to fix it? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why the two `onOptionsItemSelected`? Just use a `switch case` to see which menu is selected and start the corresponding activity.

Comment: is the first menuitem working and the second not working?

Comment: Use switch within the onOptionsItemSelected.Updating your code.

Comment: whooaa thank you, i didn't think about it before.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto: Glad to have helped. But do read up on as much as possible on developer.android.com. It really helps. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read through this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu.

This section demonstrates the ideal way of using the `onOptionsItemSelected` method (actually, anything to do with `Menus`).

The excerpt from the page (related to your situation):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

      switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case 1:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Studentsite News", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ssnews.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return true;               
        case 2:
      Toast.makeText(this, "About", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, about.class);
    startActivity(i);

     return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


     }

  }
```